# Xamarin Forms imagecircle plugin 'ImageCircleRenderer' does not contain a definition for 'Init'

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin Forms and open source plugin imagecircle plugin for rounded Image. After installing this plugin in all my apps -standard shared platform,iOS and Android and then writing the

```
ImageCircleRenderer.Init()
```

code in all 3 apps, I'm getting Error

'ImageCircleRenderer' does not contain a definition for 'Init'

Comment: you only call the Init in the platform projects, not in the shared project.  Do you have the correct namespace?  Are you placing it after the Forms.Init?

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 0):

I just test and everything works on my side. Here is the steps:

Install the `imagecircle plugin`:

[image]

Then in Android.project:

```
using ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Droid;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

        ImageCircleRenderer.Init();

        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
```

In iOS.Project:

```
using ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.iOS;

public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
{
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

        ImageCircleRenderer.Init();

        LoadApplication(new App());

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
}
```

You can try to clean/rebuild or re-install the plugin if it still does't work.